# php how to preserve session state for prolonged period of time? troubles

Tags: php, session

I'm having trouble preserving session state for a prolonged period of time. I use sessions to preserve login state. I require the below snippet of code at the top of each of my pages before any other code. First off, is there any settings I'm missing?

```
session_cache_expire(2880); //set session to expire in 48 hours 
session_start();
```

Some people are logged out before the 48 hour expiration time. What types of things could cause this? I know closing the browser kills the session and this is not the case.

As far as I can tell it happens when the user is inactive for several hours or more.

Users are never logged off while actively browsing the site.

What gives?

Comment: I'd have thought that writing session data out to some sort of permanent storage (ie. a database) then reloading it when the user returns to the site would be a better solution than abusing the session like this.

Comment: I don't know about abuse... Using a single session variable to keep track of user being logged in.. is well.. ok.

Comment: I agree with Ant, a long session lifetime increases the window in which a hacker can gain access to the session.  Personally I tend to use a 30-minute timeout.  If the user interacts with the session, the 30 minutes starts again.  Would you leave your computer unattended whilst switched on, logged on and unlocked for 2 days?

Comment: It really depends on how sensitive your information is, if someone really wanted to break into your computer a session time of 30 minutes will not stop them.

Comment: I was thinking more about where the session is stored:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.requirements.php

Sessions are stored in RAM.  Therefore, setting the session to last 48 hours is a) totally non-scalable, and b) a bad idea if your server ever gets rebooted.

Comment: A) I don't really know any facts on scalability but I can't imagine the session variable itself consuming much space. Ram is cheap and unless I planned on making the next facebook or myspace I don't think it'll be a problem.

B) If the web server hosting your site reboots people accessing will losing connection anyway you put it...

Besides, a webserver shouldn't need to be rebooted often if ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only affects how long the browser caches session pages for.

Try setting the gc_maxlifetime variable (value is in seconds):

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "172800");
```

Comment: Both ini_set and session.gc_maxlifetime have been in PHP since the PHP4 days so they'll work on 5.1, 5.2, 5.3... whatever.

Comment: oh, I read the manual and it said PHP5 >= 5.3. I didn't read it correctly at first. Thanks!

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, thanks Andy! 

According to php manual by default maxlifetime is set to 1440 seconds (24 minutes), this was likely the problem.

http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-99224.html

The 2nd post down is an interesting read, I'm not sure if this could be another reason but the frequency of users losing session is better when extending the garbage collection maxlifetime.

Answer (score 1):

session_cache_expire only effects HTTP cache expiration time. What you want to do is use cookies to set your session data.

The following is an example I have used for login/logout sessions.

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($action == "logout") {
  setcookie('sId', '', time()-60*60*24*365); //set sId cookie to expire

  session_destroy();
} else if (empty($_SESSION['sId'])) { //if cannot get sId from session
  if (isset($_COOKIE['sId'])) { //check if sId is in cookie
    $sId = $_COOKIE['sId'];
  } else { //get a new sId and set to cookie
    $sId = session_id();
    setcookie('sId', $sId, time()+60*60*24*365);
  }

  $_SESSION['sId'] = $sId; 
} else { //get sId from session
    $sId = $_SESSION['sId'];
}

?>
```

Comment: My session variable I store is the user login id, is that a good idea to store that in a cookie?

Comment: Cookies are not a great way at all to store session data - especially if it's sensitive because it gets passed to and from the server with every request.  It's the session ID that you want to store in the cookies which PHP does as standard, then you use php.ini to customise the session handling (such as timeout) or write your own.